# ORDER BY query with WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Guys I am trying to display all records from a table with the exception of top 3 latest records. I have tried WHERE NOT EXISTS but I can't seem to get it to work. Help will be appreciated.

`EDITED` :
Query :

```
SELECT  [Subject],
        IssueDate,
        (SELECT d.DepartName 
        FROM dbo.Department d 
        WHERE d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID) AS 'Department',
        Body, 
        NoticeImage, 
        Icon 
FROM dbo.Notice n 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT TOP(3) [Subject],
                        IssueDate,
                        (SELECT d.DepartName 
                        FROM dbo.Department d 
                        WHERE d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID) AS 'Department', 
                        Body, 
                        NoticeImage, 
                        Icon 
                    FROM dbo.Notice n 
                    ORDER BY IssueDate DESC)
                    ORDER BY IssueDate DESC
```

It does get executed but the rows returned are 0 even though there is data in db. There is no null value in database if that matters.

Comment: for a start, ORDER clauses should always be after the WHERE clause. See what happens if you remove the ORDER BY, then see what happens if you move it to the last line.

Comment: Sorry for that, please see my edited question.

Comment: Ok. Could you explain what are you trying to find? Like, "the notices, and their respective department, excluding the top 3 notices in the company".

Comment: Yes, I am already displaying latest 3 notices (based on IssueDate) on a page, I need this stored procedure to return all notices except for those 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error is the the order by clause has to come after the where clause.  I also think you are takeing the wrong approach.  I would try something like this:

```
select myfields
from mytables
where SomeIdField not in 
(select top 3 SomeIdField
from mytables
where whatver
order by someField desc)
and other conditions
order by something
```

You can fill in the details.

Comment: Thank you. I used what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to skip the first 3 rows.

```
SELECT  [Subject],
        IssueDate,
        (SELECT d.DepartName 
        FROM dbo.Department d 
        WHERE d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID) AS 'Department',
        Body, 
        NoticeImage, 
        Icon 
FROM dbo.Notice n 
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC 
OFFSET 3;
```

it would be more efficient to use a JOIN instead of a subquery

```
SELECT  [Subject],
        n.IssueDate,
        d.DepartName AS 'Department',
        n.Body, 
        n.NoticeImage, 
        n.Icon 
FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN dbo.Department d ON   d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC 
OFFSET 3;
```

Edit: dirty trick for versions without OFFSET clause

```
select * from
    (SELECT  [Subject],
        n.IssueDate,
        d.DepartName AS 'Department',
        n.Body, 
        n.NoticeImage, 
        n.Icon,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IssueDate DESC ) AS RowNum 
FROM dbo.Notice n INNER JOIN dbo.Department d ON   d.DepartmentID = n.DepartmentID
) subquery
where RowNum>3 
ORDER BY IssueDate DESC
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. This is the error I am getting while trying to execute above queries. RDBMS is SQL server 2008 r2. I believe OFFSET is a feature of MSSQL2012..

Comment: Hmmm perhaps the syntax is ```OFFSET 3 ROWS```

Comment: OFFSET is not recognized in sql server 2008r2

Comment: Thank you so much for your help amenadiel! Really appreciate it.